# It's all in the 2's follow-up question

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid, slitherlink

This is in regards to the solution in [Slitherlink - It's all in the 2s](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55702/slitherlink-its-all-in-the-2s)

I know it may seem dumb, but I don't understand the logic behind the second 2 chain in the solution. To help provide clarity in my question, imagine that each dot corresponds to a Letter-Number coordinates like

```
7 
6 
5 
4 
3 
2 
1 
  ABCDEFG
```

The line the is next to the top 2 in the diagonal pair where the line goes from G-4 to G-5.

I'm also lost on why there is a line from G-2 to G-3?

Thanks in advance for teaching me.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, the chain is not immediately obvious but I think this is the line of reasoning

> The highlighted node in the picture cannot provide an entry or exit from the 2 square for the path
>  [image]
>  This means that the two adjacent nodes are the entry/exit points (the path either uses the top and left sides or bottom and right). The knock-on effect is that the highlighted node below is also not an entry/exit node for its square
>  [image]
>  and similarly the two adjacent nodes (to the right and below) are entry/exit for that 2 square (below-right of the highlighted node). In particular, the following node is an entry exit point
>  [image]
>  as must be the node above and to the right and the exiting path can only be continued upwards from there (i.e, G-4 to G-5)

The G2-G3 line only comes after filling in a few lines first

> [image]
>  And then we see the chain
>  [image]